# Reducing the order of a second-order differential equation for a boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I want to numerically solve for $y(x)$. I have the boundary conditions $y(x_a)=1$ and $y(x_b)=1$ as well as the following second-order set of differential equations:

$$
\frac{\text{d}z(x)}{\text{d} x} = - \frac{f_1(x)}{x^2 f_2(x)} y(x)
$$
$$
z(x) = \frac{ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + f_3(x) }{ c x^2 f_1(x) }
$$

I understand that to solve a BVP I need to reduce these equations to first-order. How can I do that?

Edit: or are they already first order, I just need to rearrange the $z(x)$ equation?

Comment: Do you need to do this with your own code from scratch? This will probably not take you nearly so much work if you use a standard solver like bvp4c or bvp5c in Matlab.

Comment: @Ian I do not need to write my own solver. This is for my research, not a class, so I really just want to get the right answer. I am using python and tried with solve_bvp but didn't have much luck. Do you have any python recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

To solve a BVP you do not need to reduce it to first order. Since your boundary conditions are both on $y(x)$, its much easier to get a second order equation for $y(x)$ and solve that. From $y(x)$ you can easily find $z(x)$ so your problem will be solved.

The trick to get a nice form for solving your problem is to take the derivative of your second equation and put the first one into the second :
$$
-\frac{f_1(x)}{x^2f_2(x)}y(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}+f_3(x)}{c x^2 f_1(x)}
$$
This is now a second order equation for $y(x)$, which you can solve using the usual tricks. I would recommend using finite differences if you're writing your own solver. Consider solving $y(x)$ on grids where $\vec{x} = [x_0, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n]$ and $\vec{y} = [y_0, y_1, ..., y_{i-1}, y_i, y_{i+1}, ..., y_n]$. The operator $y''(x) = h^{-2}/2 *(y_{i-1} -2 y_i + y_{i+1})$ where $h = \Delta x$, the grid step size, can be easily represented by a sparse tridiagonal matrix (and the same goes for other operators, you can find tables for finite differences on wiki). You can enforce your boundary conditions in a matrix by putting $1$ on the main diagonal and you will end up looking at a matrix system that looks like $M \vec{y} = \vec{b}$ which can be solved by linear algebra techniques.

EDIT : 
On non-uniform grids, you can still use finite differences, but you have to slightly change the formulas. Typically, finite difference schemes are obtained from Taylor expensions $f(x_i + \Delta x_i) = f(x_i) + f'(x_i) \Delta x_i + O(\Delta x_i^2)$ and if your grid is non-uniform, the coefficients will depend on the local grid size. You can find such formulas easily on the internet (see http://fundamentalthinking.blogspot.com/2014/08/second-order-finite-difference-schemes.html for instance).

The matrix $M$ in your case does not depend on $y$ as your system is linear in $y$. Consider solving the equation $y'' + a(x) y' + b(x) y  =c(x)$, a general second order ODE. In a linearly spaced grid, $y'(x) = (2h)^{-1} (y(x+\Delta) - y(x-\Delta))$, which translates into $y'_i = (2h)^{-1} (y_{i+1} - y_{i-1})$. The matrix $A$ for the operator $a(x) y'(x)$ is a $N*N$ matrix, one line for each element of $\vec{y}$. The $i^{th}$ line elements are given by $A_{i,i-1} = -(2h)^{-1}a(x_i)$ and $A_{i, i+1} = (2h)^{-1} a(x_i)$. Also notice $y(x) = I$ and $c(x)$ is actually a vector. This matrix construction is fine for all elements with the exception of the end points where you will enforce boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and the description for solving this kind of problem. I was hoping to avoid writing my own solver, but if it's necessary, I am wondering if you would possibly be able to supply some minimal pseudo-code for its implementation? I have the vectors $\vec x$, $\vec f_1$, $\vec f_2$, $\vec f_3$ and the constant $c$ already calculated, but I am confused about how to set up the matrix $M$. Also, I should perhaps mention that $x_2-x_1 \neq x_3-x_2$, i.e. the grid isn't regularly spaced (although I could interpolate).

Comment: In particular I am confused because the construction of $M$ depends on the values of $y$ which are what we are trying to find in the first place. Perhaps a link to lead me in the right direction would suffice to clear up my confusion though.